# Arc length of a singular function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So i need help proving something, So if i have a singular function continuous of bounded variation, which implies that its a generalized derivative is singular we are going to have that $ \lambda(I) = m(I) + |\mu|(I)$ , where $\lambda$ is the arc length ,$\mu$ is the generalized derivative of the function and $m$ is the lebesgue measure.I know that $ \lambda(I) \leq m(I) + |\mu|(I)$ is going to be true for any continuous function of bounded variation. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.